# Positioning layers in LayerDrawable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple map with a LayerDrawable where the first layer is the map drawable and the second layer is a marker. I want to position the marker to be on the exact position I want it to be on every / most device(s), how do I achieve that kind of thing?

The way I have it set up right now is that the marker is moved with setLayerInset, but the position of the marker will differ between devices like crazy.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int phoneHeight, phoneWidth;
private ZoomageView zoom;
float x, y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setMarkerPos(0.279f, 0.245f);
    createMap();
}

public void createMap() {
    zoom = (ZoomageView) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
    phoneHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    phoneWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    Drawable map = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map);
    Drawable marker = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_marker);

    Drawable[] layers = {map, marker};
    LayerDrawable layer = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    layer.setLayerSize(1, 30, 35);
    layer.setLayerInsetLeft(1, getX());
    layer.setLayerInsetTop(1, getY());

    zoom.setImageDrawable(layer);
    zoom.setScaleRange(.5f, 8);

}

public void setMarkerPos(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return (int) (phoneHeight * x);
}

public int getY() {
    return (int) (phoneHeight * y);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include some of the code you are using?

Comment: I just added the code.